# How to add point to a specific value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a value of 25 of packaging and I want to add pieces as points. 
Suppose if I add 25.10 should be taken as one carton and ten pieces,
or 35 total, but when I try this it adds a point to a hundred. 
It actually thinks that 10 out of 100.

Comment: Adding an image of what you are getting and hopefully what you are looking for would help.  I realize you are trying to enter things and aren't getting what you want. Put a ' (atrophy) ahead of the values so Excel treats them as text.  That way you can show us the hopped result.

Comment: I have a product packaging consisting of 25 packs, but then in a cell, I want to type 1.10 which should automatically return the value of 35 rather than calculation separately and adding manually 35, or say 25.10 should return 35 hope you got the point

Comment: Have two columns for entry: Cartons and Pieces. Enter 1 in the Cartons column and 10 in the pieces column. A third column can be =Cartons+Pieces

Comment: Could you provide the sample here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `25.10` (as a number) in cell `A1`
and you want to get `35` in some other cell (say, `B1`), enter

```
=INT(A1) + 100*MOD(A1,1)
```

into that second cell (`B1`). 
This takes the integer part of the value (`INT(25.10)` is 25)
and the portion to the right of the decimal point,
converting that to an integer by multiplying it by 100,
and adds them.

This might not do what you really want. 
(Your question is hard to understand. 
It's great that you included *an* example,
but it's often much more useful to give a few examples.) 
For example, mathematically, 25.1, 25.10 and 25.100 are all the same number. 
If you type `25.1`, and you use the formula I gave above,
you will still get 35 as a result (and not 26). 
If you type `25.107`, you will get 35.7 (25+10.7) rather than 132 (25+107).

Oops.  I just noticed in the comments
that you're saying `1.something`
rather than `25.something`. 
(Also, you've changed from "25" to "24".) 
If you have `1.10` (as a number) in cell `A1`
and you want to get `35` in some other cell (say, `B1`), enter

```
=25*INT(A1) + 100*MOD(A1,1)
```

into that second cell (`B1`). 
If you have `1.1` (as a number)
and you want to get `26`, use

```
=25*INT(A1) + 10*MOD(A1,1)
```

If the number (25) can vary from workbook to workbook,
put it into the workbook (let's say in cell `P1`) and use

```
=$P$1*INT(A1) + 100*MOD(A1,1)
```

If you need to have a variable number of digits
to the right of the decimal point —
in other words, if you want `1.1` and `1.10` to give different results —
as shown in my examples above,
you will need to enter your hybrid value
(`something.something`)
as text rather than as a number. 
If that's the case, edit your question to make it clearer and more complete.

P.S. If you want `1.1` to be treated as `1.10`
(remember, 1.1 and 1.10 *are **the same number***)
but you want `1.20`, `1.30`, etc., to be treated as `1.2`, `1.3`, etc.,
that may be possible. 
*If that's the case,
**[edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1707582/edit)** to make it clearer and more complete.* 
(*And* add a comment to let me know that you edited the question.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, although this works, but now in all scenarios, I'll be more specific on that, I have a package consisting of 24 packs, but often I need to add lose packs in sales for example I can use 1 for 24 packs carton, I can add 1 in carton cell but it would require anothr cell to add 3 packs indivdally then summing them up it's messy, I would want to round down under 24 rather then 100 so when ever I type 1.3 it should return 27 (24+3=27) 1.6 should return 30

Comment: Scott. thank you very much, =$P$1*INT(A1) + 100*MOD(A1,1)
 worked exactly what I wanted, thumbs up